# How can I cast an object as parameter of Function1[Array[_], Unit] inScala

Tags: scala, wildcard, type-parameter

```
class MyClass(functions: Seq[Function1[Array[_], Unit]) {
  def foo(parametersForEachFunction: Seq[Array[_]]) {
    assert(functions.size == parametersForEachFunction.size)
    for ((function, parameter) <- functions zip parametersForEachFunction) {
      // Assume each parameter is suitable for the funcition
      // What type parameter I should wrote in asInstanceOf?
      function(parameter.asInstanceOf[ ?????? ])
    }
  }
}
```

I know an `asInstanceOf` is required here, but I don't know what type parameter I should wrote in asInstanceOf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to cast, you are doing it wrong. Whenever you think you should cast something, rollback and try something else. There are exceptions -- if the documentation of something explicitly tell you to cast, well, you have to cast. But don't count on *you* have such an exception: you probably don't.

As in this case.

```
scala> class MyClass(functions: Seq[Function1[Array[_], Unit]]) {
     |   def foo(parametersForEachFunction: Seq[Array[_]]) {
     |     assert(functions.size == parametersForEachFunction.size)
     |     for ((function, parameter) <- functions zip parametersForEachFunction) {
     |       function(parameter)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
defined class MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

`Function0` takes only one type param, so not sure what you're doing.

If you're thinking about passing arbitrary argument to arbitrary arity of functions, you probably could look into `Function2` etc's `curried` method or `Function` object's `tupled`. I vaguely recall scalaz being able to do this kind of stuff out of the box, but not sure.

Comment: No, arity-stuff is the realm of shapeless.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `Function1`, since you want to pass one parameter.  `Function0`, as the name implies, takes zero parameters.  I prefer using `A => B` to `Function1[A,B]`, so I'll write it that way.  (Note that all functions have one return value.)

```
class MyClass(fns: Seq[Array[_] => Unit]) {
  def foo(parms: Seq[Array[_]]) {
    for ((f,p) <- fns zip parms) {
      f(p)
    }
  }
}
```

Also, `Array` and *only* `Array` is non-generic.  You can't pass an `Array[Int]` or an `Array[String]` in for an `Array[_]`.  So the above probably doesn't do what you want:

```
scala> new MyClass(Seq((a: Array[_]) => println(a.length)))
res0: MyClass = MyClass@3fee3c8d

scala> new MyClass(Seq((a: Array[String]) => println(a.mkString)))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String] => Unit
 required: Array[_] => Unit
              new MyClass(Seq((a: Array[String]) => println(a.mkString)))

scala> new MyClass(Seq(((a: Array[String]) => println(a.mkString)).asInstanceOf[Array[_]=>Unit]))
res4: MyClass = MyClass@4b9cee52

scala> new MyClass(Seq(((a: Array[Int]) => println(a.sum)).asInstanceOf[Array[_]=>Unit]))
res5: MyClass = MyClass@2357f593

scala> res5.foo(Seq(Array(1,2,3).asInstanceOf[Array[_]]))
6
```

Ugh!  Maybe you can find another way to represent what you want?  (Since I don't know your use case, I hesitate to recommend anything.)